# Unity saving via playerprefs bugged?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Sorry, I that I included all the code but I really can't find the error: I play and save and after I buy something with the `BuyTaxes` or `Buymarket` and quit and stop it and play it again it shows all the UI shows and all the prices for the market and the discount use are set to **0**. But I cant figure out why.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class GameScript : MonoBehaviour
{
public Text GoldText;
public Text ArmyPowerText;
public Text PlayerNametext;

public Text Button1Text;
public Text Button2Text;

public int gold;
public int armypower;
public string PlayerName;
public int Level;
public int Income;
public int incomeboost;
public int discount;
public float lvlremainder;


public GameObject ButtonHolder;
public Slider LevelBar;
public float LevelProgress;
private float FillSpeed = 0.5f;



public GameObject UIHolder;
public GameObject StartForm;
public InputField NameInput;
public GameObject ArmyUI;
public GameObject InvestUI;
public GameObject LaboratoryUI;

private float time = 0.0f;
public float IncomePerdiod = 5f;


public bool GameStart = true;

//Invest Prices

//Market
public int marketprice;
public int marketlevel;
public Text marketpricetext;
public Text markettext;

//Taxes
public int taxesprice;
public int taxeslevel;
public Text taxespricetext;
public Text taxestext;


void Start()
{
    Load();
    if(GameStart == true)
    {

        gold = 100;
        armypower = 0;
        Level = 1;
        LevelProgress = 0;

        //Laboratory
        discount = 1;
        Income = 1;
        incomeboost = 1;

        //Invest
        marketlevel = 0;
        taxeslevel = 0;

        ArmyUIHide();
        InvestUIHide();
        ButtonHide();
        UIHide();
        StartForm.SetActive(true);
        Save();
    }

    if (GameStart == false)
    {
        StartForm.SetActive(false);
        ArmyUIHide();
        InvestUIHide();
        ButtonShow();
        UIShow();
        Save();
    }
}


void Update()
{
    if(time >= IncomePerdiod)
    {
        time = 0.0f;
        gold += Income * incomeboost;
    }

    time += Time.deltaTime;
    Save();
    GoldText.text = "Gold: " + gold;
    ArmyPowerText.text = "Army Power: " + armypower;
    PlayerNametext.text = PlayerName + " LVL " + Level;

    //Market
    markettext.text = "Market LVL " + marketlevel; 
    marketpricetext.text = marketprice.ToString();
    marketprice = 50 * discount;

    //Taxes
    taxestext.text = "Taxes LVL " + taxeslevel;
    taxespricetext.text = taxesprice.ToString();
    taxesprice = 250 * discount;

    if (LevelBar.value < LevelProgress)
    {
        LevelBar.value += FillSpeed * Time.deltaTime;
    }

    if (LevelBar.value > LevelProgress)
    {
        LevelBar.value = LevelProgress;
    }

    if (LevelProgress >= 1)
    {
        Level++;
        LevelProgress = 0;
    }
}

public void Save()
{
    //UI
    PlayerPrefs.SetString("gold", gold.ToString());
    PlayerPrefs.SetString("armypower", armypower.ToString());
    PlayerPrefs.SetString("GameStart", GameStart.ToString());
    PlayerPrefs.SetString("PlayerName", PlayerName.ToString());
    PlayerPrefs.SetString("Level", Level.ToString());
    PlayerPrefs.SetString("LevelProgress", LevelProgress.ToString());

    //Laboratory
    PlayerPrefs.SetString("discount", discount.ToString());
    PlayerPrefs.SetString("Income", Income.ToString());
    PlayerPrefs.SetString("incomeboost", incomeboost.ToString());

    //Invest
    PlayerPrefs.SetString("marketlevel", marketlevel.ToString());
    PlayerPrefs.SetString("taxeslevel", taxeslevel.ToString());
}

public void Load()
{
    //UI
    gold = int.Parse(PlayerPrefs.GetString("gold", "100"));
    armypower = int.Parse(PlayerPrefs.GetString("armypower", "0"));
    GameStart = bool.Parse(PlayerPrefs.GetString("GameStart", "true"));
    PlayerName = PlayerPrefs.GetString("PlayerName", "Guest");
    Level = int.Parse(PlayerPrefs.GetString("Level", "1"));
    LevelProgress = int.Parse(PlayerPrefs.GetString("LevelProgress", "0"));

    //Laboratory
    discount = int.Parse(PlayerPrefs.GetString("discount", "1"));
    Income = int.Parse(PlayerPrefs.GetString("Income", "1"));
    incomeboost = int.Parse(PlayerPrefs.GetString("incomeboost", "1"));

    //Invest
    marketlevel = int.Parse(PlayerPrefs.GetString("marketlevel", "50"));
    taxeslevel = int.Parse(PlayerPrefs.GetString("taxeslevel", "250"));
}

public void ButtonHide()
{
    ButtonHolder.SetActive(false);
}

public void ButtonShow()
{
    ButtonHolder.SetActive(true);
}

public void UIHide()
{
    UIHolder.SetActive(false);
}

public void UIShow()
{
    UIHolder.SetActive(true);
}

public void ArmyUIShow()
{
    ArmyUI.SetActive(true);
}

public void ArmyUIHide()
{
    ArmyUI.SetActive(false);
}

public void LaboratoryUIShow()
{
    LaboratoryUI.SetActive(true);
}

public void LaboratoryUIHide()
{
    LaboratoryUI.SetActive(false);
}

public void InvestUIShow()
{
    InvestUI.SetActive(true);
}

public void InvestUIHide()
{
    InvestUI.SetActive(false);
}

public void EnterName()
{
    PlayerName = NameInput.text;
    StartForm.SetActive(false);
    UIShow();
    GameStart = false;
    ButtonShow();
}

public void ArmyClick()
{
    ArmyUIShow();
    ButtonHide();
    LaboratoryUIHide();
    InvestUIHide();
}

public void InvestClick()
{
    InvestUIShow();
    ButtonHide();
    LaboratoryUIHide();
    ArmyUIHide();
}

public void LaboratoryClick()
{
    ArmyUIHide();
    ButtonHide();
    LaboratoryUIShow();
    InvestUIHide();
}

public void Home()
{
    ArmyUIHide();
    InvestUIHide();
    ButtonShow();
    LaboratoryUIHide();
}


//Buy Invest
public void BuyMarket()
{
    if(gold >= marketprice && marketlevel < 5)
    {
        marketlevel++;
        Income += 1;
        gold -= marketprice;
        if (LevelProgress < 1f - 0.05f)
        {
            LevelProgress += 0.15f;
        }

        else
        {
            lvlremainder += (LevelProgress + 0.05f - 1f);
            Level++;
            LevelProgress = 0;
            LevelProgress += lvlremainder;

        }
    }
}

public void BuyTaxes()
{
    if (gold >= taxesprice && taxeslevel < 10)
    {
        taxeslevel++;
        Income += 3;
        gold -= taxesprice;
        if (LevelProgress < 1f - 0.15f)
        {
            LevelProgress += 0.15f;
        }

        else 
        {
            lvlremainder += (LevelProgress + 0.15f - 1f);
            Level++;
            LevelProgress = 0;
            LevelProgress += lvlremainder;

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Set Gamestart to false before you call save in Start(). And move if gamestart is false logic above so it doesn't get run after you set it to false.

Comment: Have you tried it Swen?

Comment: It didn't work.

Comment: Try putting PlayerPrefs.Save() at the end of your save method. Also as someone said it is very resource intensive to save playerprefs in Update() so you should call your save function in OnApplicationQuit().

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the fault I parsed as int for a float that messed the whole saving system up!

Answer (score 0):

The saving system in your code is not developed correctly, remove the `Save()` method call from the `Start` and `Update` methods, and call it only when the necessary event occurs, such as the end of the game.

Answer (score 0):

Do local prop like this to save data:

```
private int Gold
{
    get => PlayerPrefs.GetInt("gold");
    set => PlayerPrefs.SetInt("gold", value);
}
```